# GAS .withSuccessHandler fails with error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have written a Google Sheets add-on that uses a modal dialog as the interface. I was having trouble getting the success handler to run, so I created a skeleton interface for testing, and have the same issue.

Whenever the server-side function returns, the function specified in the success handler should run. Instead, it throws an error "Untaught TypeError: a is not a function". I am able to manually trigger the function specified for the handler via a button (added for demonstration purposes only. Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>

    function success(){
      document.getElementById("waitMessage").innerHTML = "TEST";
    }

    function testFunc(){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler("success").serverSideFunc();
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Click the button to close the window
    </p>
    <form>
       //Doesn't work
     <input type="button" name="test" value="Server-side test" onclick="testFunc()">
       //Works
     <input type="button" name="test-client" value="Client-side test" onclick="success()">
    </form>
     <div id="waitMessage">
     <p></p>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

.gs script file below:

```
function serverSideFunc(){
  Logger.log("");
}
```

As you can see, the script file is just a dummy function designed to trigger the success handler.

What's going on here? Have I missed something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not having an error returned.  You do not put quotes around the function name to run:

```
function testFunc(){
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).serverSideFunc();
}
```

Comment: Glad it was something simple. As far as the error, I should have said that I'm getting an error in the Javascript console in the browser. Definitely not important, but if you understand why that is, I'd appreciate an explanation, just for my own education.

Comment: Need someone else to explain that. Appears to be something happening on Google's side and how they treat the script.